# Length of Rope in Tug Of War Matter?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, string

I had a question about Tug of War Game, Does the length of the rope really matter, whats the difference between a  50cm rope and a 5meter Rope in Force, Torque And Safety in Tug Of War.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the rope does not matter on the level of fundamental physics principles, but it may matter on the level of human body mechanics.

Humans are much better at pulling when they can lean their body at an angle to the ground, so their hands are ahead of their feet in the direction they want to pull. If the rope is too short, it might be impossible for both players to adopt this stance, making the game much harder.

However, once the rope is long enough for both players to lean over as much as they want without interfering with each other there is no physics that would make the length of ropes have any effect on the game.

Comment: Luke, I agree with and like your answer very much!

Comment: Another correction comes into play for very long ropes: the sag of the center section will help to ground the front members of each team making line-up selection a factor in the real game when is would seem immaterial in a naive analysis.

Comment: Also, with a long rope the stretchability of the rope will become more noticeable.

Comment: Thank you experts, something was wondering me what about the center of mass, the length of the rope affects center of mass right?

Comment: The center of mass of a rope is pretty much always going to be right in the middle no matter how long it is. A longer rope would be heavier in total too, but since a person can only hold a section of the rope in the air anyway that doesn't matter.